# Concatenate pairs of consecutive sublists in a list using Python

Tags: python, list

How would you combine sublists within a list by pairs?
For example with:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

the result would be:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by append a sublist within a list of pairs? Can you please explain how you got the result? Do you just want to extend every consecutive list with the one after it?

Comment: Yes, it is basically that, joining or extending each sublist with its next consecutive sublist but of course avoiding duplication of the elements.

Comment: Can you please add an example of input/output with duplicated values?

Comment: list1=[[1,1,2], [3,1,4],[5,6,7],[1,1,2]] restult in list1=[[1,1,2,3,1,4],[5,6,7,1,1,2]]

Comment: what has duplicated values got to do with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `zip_longest` with a fill value (in case your list has an odd number of sublists) to zip an iterator over `list1`. Running a list comprehension over the zip generator object allows you to concatenate the consecutive pairs of lists:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest # izip_longest in Python 2.x
>>> x = iter(list1)
>>> [a+b for a, b in zip_longest(x, x, fillvalue=[])]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a list comprehension (but be careful with the indexes!). It works for lists with an even or odd number of sublists:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
n = len(list1)

[list1[i] + (list1[i+1] if i+1 < n else []) for i in xrange(0, n, 2)]
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[7,8],[9,10]]

length = len(list1)
new_list = [ list1[i]+list1[i+1] if i+1 < length 
                                 else [list1[i]] for i in range(0,length,2) ] 

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[7,8],[9,10]]
>>> list1
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Now we can do:

```
>>> test = [list1[0]+list1[1]]+[list1[2]+list1[3]]+list1[4]
>>> test
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], 9, 10]
>>>
```

I am sure there is a better way, but this is the way I can think of!

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
from itertools import islice, chain

print([list(chain.from_iterable(islice(list1, i, i + 2)))
       for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)])
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Or without islice:

```
print([list(chain.from_iterable(list1[i:i+2]))
       for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)])
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop:

```
list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[7,8],[9,10]]

newlist = []

for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    newlist.append(list1[i] + list1[i+1])
if len(list1) % 2 > 0:
    newlist.append(list1[-1])

print newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is (I hope) a correct solution:

```
def pair_up(ls):
    new_list = []
    every_other1 = ls[::2]
    every_other2 = ls[1::2]

    for i in range(len(every_other2)):
        new_list.append(every_other1[i]+every_other2[i])

    if len(ls) % 2 == 1:
        new_list.append(ls[-1])

    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on same list with removing n-ths[-1] odd sublists:

```
for i in range(len(l)/2):#here we go only to last even item
    l[i]+=l[i+1]#adding odd sublist to even sublist
    l.pop(i+1)#removing even sublist
```